# How to encode strings in JSON in a PHP form?

Tags: php, json, forms, get

I have this form and he makes a txt file from a text input. Example for the file that the form make:

`[{message: Test }]`

But I want it to be:

`[{"message": "Test" }]`

So how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them when you write in the file:

```
fwrite($file, "[{message: \"$data\" }]");
```

or with `'`

```
fwrite($file, '[{message: "' . $data . '" }]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Created an array of your out put and json encoded it.

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
      if (empty($_GET['filename']) || empty($_GET['data'])) {
        echo '<br /> ' . 'fail';
      }
      if (file_exists('uploads/' . $_GET['filename'] . '.txt')) {
       echo '<br />' . 'Sorry, file already exist';
    }else {
      $filename = $_GET['filename'];
      $data = $_GET['data'];
      $myjs=array("message"=>$data);
      $msg= json_encode($myjs);
      $file = fopen('uploads/' . $filename . '.txt', 'w');
      fwrite($file,$msg);
      fclose($file);
    }
  }
```